# Validation for dynamic radio buttons Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to validate my dynamic radio inputs. I have this in my view
view.blade.php:

```
echo "<span class='error'>".$errors->first('sar')."</span><td></tr>";

for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
echo"<td>"; ?>
<input class='radio-inline' name='sar[<?php echo $number; ?>]' type='radio' value='<?php echo $i; ?>' ><?php    echo "</td>";}
```

Controller:

```
//valida pontas -- 
$this->validate($request, [
    'sar' => 'required'
]);
```

I have tried: inside view  `$vf = 'sar['.$fcid.']'; $errors->first($vf)` and inside my controller: `'sar[$i]' => 'required'`

So the for loop dynamically creates radio buttons with names like 'sar[1]' in my this validate i dont know how I would validate each dynamically created radio input... Any ideas on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a Change with

```
//valida pontas -- 
$this->validate($request, [
    'sar.*' => 'required'
]);
```

This is for Laravel 5.2 or greater one

Comment: it submits the form and bypasses the validation,

Comment: Are you doing form post with Ajax or without AJax?

Comment: Form post without ajax, on submit check validate all request['']; its the laravel default...or basic way right?

Comment: sorry for taking long to respond

Comment: I guess for this part I´ll have to relay on javascript

Comment: You can do any way either by jquery ajax or make traditional form post directly

Answer (score 0):

The validation rule submitted by Ronak is correct:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'sar.*' => 'required'
]);
```

But if you don't select the radio button, the input is not sent at all and so, it can't be validated. One way to bypass this problem is to put a hidden input with the same name and a void value before the radio input. So your html becomes:

```
echo "<span class='error'>".$errors->first('sar')."</span><td></tr>";
for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
    echo"<td>"; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name='sar[<?php echo $number; ?>]' value=''>
    <input class='radio-inline' name='sar[<?php echo $number; ?>]' type='radio' value='<?php echo $i; ?>' ><?php    
    echo "</td>";
}
```